# extracting vertices of a triangle which is in y-coordinate matrix format

Tags: matlab, vector, fuzzy

I'm using the "fuzarith" function for division of two fuzzy numbers;

> C = fuzarith(X, A, B, operator)
>   x is a row vector that defines the x coordinates of the points at which the operation(in this case a division) is carried out. I think the mathematical term is abcissa.
>
> A and B are triangular fuzzy numbers defined by their 3 vertices using the function trimf(x,[a b c]), where a,b and c are the x-coordinates of the vertices as shown below:
>   for
>
> > x=0:0.1:10; and 
> >     P=trimf(x,[3 6 8]);

[image: triangular fuzzy number]

Now if I use the division operator, let's say I do [3 6 8]/[1 2 3],
the result,r, is mathematically [1 3 8] but matlab gives me an <101x1> column vector of the ordinates of the plot of r v/s x.

The question is how to extract the 3 vertices from the column vector.

Answer (score 1):

For this or similar problem you can do:

```
y = fuzarith(x, A, B, 'div');    
result = x([find(y ~= 0, 1, 'first') - 1, find(y == 1), find(y ~= 0, 1, 'last') + 1]);
```

Comment: the "find(y == 1)" part can be problematic if there is no 1 in the vector y. This can arise if the number of abscissa is too small. 
>For example [4 5 6]/[1 2 3]=[1.33 2.5 6]
but if x=0:1:10, result becomes [1 6]. Any way to cater for this?

Comment: If this can help  I've tried x=0:1/n:10,n=2,3,...,12.

Correct answer at n=6 and 12. 

(1x2) matrix at n=3,5,7,9,11.

Comment: Well, you can replace `find(y == 1)` with `find(y==max(y))`. This will give you index of a maximum.

Comment: This won't work as `find(y==max(y))` will find the point near the vertex, not the vertex itself.